# How to call JHipster (Spring) OAuth2 Rest server using Postman Authentication helpers

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, jhipster, postman, spring-oauth2

Postman has [Authentication helpers](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/helpers) to help with authenticated calls and I'm trying to use the [OAuth 2.0 helper](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/helpers#oauth2) to call a REST server created by *JHipster* using **Spring** (Security, Social, etc).

I've tried a lot of configurations, this is the screen (client ID and Secret were masked):

[image: Auth helper Configuration]

For the *Authorization URL* I've tried:

- http://127.0.0.1:8080/oauth/authorize
- http://127.0.0.1:8080/#/login (the app's login route)

The closer I get from receiving a token back to Postman is:

[image: Response failed]

I don't know why it's erring like this. Maybe I'm setting the Callback URL incorrectly? Do I need to do this in the server or in the client (AngularJS)?

Does anyone have any idea of what's wrong? I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

JHipster is currently setup to use the "password" oauth2 grant type. The helper oauth2 helper only seems to work with "authorization code" and "client credentials" grant types.

What you'll want to do is first call your app's token endpoint directly as the angular app does in
src/main/webapp/scripts/components/auth/provider/auth.oauth2.service.js

```
POST http://localhost:8080/oauth/token?username=MY_USERNAME&password=MY_PASSWORD&grant_type=password&scope=read%20write
```

where your username and password can be "user" and "user" respectively, for example and with one header set:

```
Authorization: Basic AAAAAA
```

where AAAAAA is your (clientId + ":" + clientSecret)--all base64-encoded. You can use https://www.base64encode.org/. For example if your clientId is "jhipsterapp" and your clientSecret is "mySecretOAuthSecret", replace AAAAAA with "amhpcHN0ZXJhcHA6bXlTZWNyZXRPQXV0aFNlY3JldA==" since that is "jhipsterapp:mySecretOAuthSecret" base64-encoded.

That should return you an access_token. Now hit your API endpoints by calling them with the access_token from your password request in your header like this.

```
Authorization: Bearer access_token_from_earlier_token_request
```

Update: if you're using microservices and UAA, then see Niel's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45549789/1098564

Answer (score 5):

To build on @sdoxsee's answer:

Currently (August 2017) JHipster generates a class called `UaaConfiguration` with the `configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer)` method setting up the client ID, client secret, scope and grant type. Refer to these settings (including the referenced JHipster properties in the `application*.yml`) to populate the Postman authentication helper, using `/oauth/token` as both *Auth URL* and *Access Token URL*.

---

Example:

```
@Override                                                                                                     
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {                              
    /*                                                                                                        
    For a better client design, this should be done by a ClientDetailsService (similar to UserDetailsService).
     */                                                                                                       
    clients.inMemory()                                                                                        
        .withClient("web_app")                                                                                
        .scopes("openid")                                                                                     
        .autoApprove(true)                                                                                    
        .authorizedGrantTypes("implicit", "refresh_token", "password", "authorization_code")                  
        .and()                                                                                                
        .withClient(jHipsterProperties.getSecurity().getClientAuthorization().getClientId())                  
        .secret(jHipsterProperties.getSecurity().getClientAuthorization().getClientSecret())                  
        .scopes("web-app")                                                                                    
        .autoApprove(true)                                                                                    
        .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials");                                                          
}
```

And,

```
jhipster:
    security:
        client-authorization:
            client-id: internal
            client-secret: internal
```

Means your authentication helper should be populated as follows:

[image: Postman Authentication Helper]